# Vault with TLS - bad certificate error

Tags: ssl

I'm attempting to connect to vault via TLS and getting the following error:

```
2017/12/21 15:11:55 http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:62734: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

From the command vault init:

```
Error initializing Vault: Put https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/init: x509: cannot validate certificate for 127.0.0.1 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```

I've created the certificates like so:

```
openssl genrsa -out rootCA.key 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -days 1024 -out rootCA.pem
openssl genrsa -out serverCertificate.key 2048
openssl req -new -key serverCertificate.key -out serverCertificate.csr
openssl x509 -req -in serverCertificate.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out serverCertificate.crt -days 500
```

During the certificate creation I did not specify any COMMON_NAME.

This is my Vault configuration file:

```
{
  "disable_mlock": true,
  "backend": {
     "file":{
       "path": "./secrets"
    }
  },
  "listener": {
    "tcp": {
      "address":"127.0.0.1:8200",
      "tls_disable": "false",
      "tls_cert_file":"./serverCertificate.crt",
      "tls_key_file":"./serverCertificate.key"
     }
  }
}
```

Worth noting that I work on a Mac.

Please advise, what I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

When you generate your cert you need to give it some additional SANs of 127.0.0.1 since your trying to talk to Vault over 127.0.0.1. It is rejecting the certificate your using because the request is talking over 127.0.0.1 and the certificate is not configured with that IP.

This guide seems to have a decent overview of how to do it with openssl: https://gist.github.com/jchandra74/36d5f8d0e11960dd8f80260801109ab0#creating-your-self-signed-certificate-with-subject-alternative-name-san

Note you probably need to use a config file as some options can't be passed over CLI to openssl.